# Detect beginning of CSV after metadata

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am collecting data using HDT-Jena and storing it in `csv` files for further use. Unfortunately, metadata is added to the beginning and the end of the file.
**Goal:** detect where the metadata ends and where the header is located in order to read in the dataframe (using pandas).
**First Attempts and Discovered Issues:** At first, I noticed that it always begins with the string `[INFO]`.
My initial solution was:

```
def find_beginning(csv_file):
    textfile = open(csv_file)
    f = textfile.readlines()
    for num, line in enumerate(f):
        if '[INFO]' in line:
            continue
        else: 
            return num
```

Which would give me the beginning of the file and I would read it in:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, skiprows=range(0, find_beginning(csv_file)))
```

- However, in some **exceptions** the first lines might not necessarily beginn with `[INFO]` look like the following example:
  [image: Metadata in the beginning of the file]
- In addition I am working with many files with **different headers and different number or elements per row / columns in the dataframe** (thus excluding the option of looking for the header or a regular expression taking the number of elements per row as criteria).
- I also excluded the option of looking for a *comma* in a line as criteria for a row being a part of the looked for csv, due to the fact that I do not know, if a *comma* might now appear somewhere in the metadata.

Is there another way to find the header, that I am not thinking of?

Comment: I am not sure if there is another way to do this. One option is to try to make use of the header formatting. For instance, the header likely has commas and other lines don't. That way you can avoid writing explicitly for each exception case.

Comment: Your problem comes from the way the csv is built. The example you give is just the log of a maven execution. So you likely used a maven process and capture the output. As maven is used to compile/package java apps, this makes very little sense. You should explain how you produce the original csv instead of trying to fix a broken pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few Thoughts. These are all "dirty" ways:

1. Maybe you can find a "default header end-line" like `(default-cli) @ hdt-jena`, but to help on this, you have to provide more data.
2. Maybe you can name all possible columns (of all datasets). If so, you can provide these names and discard all lines with multiple NULLs afterwards. (pandas has no problem with columns that does not exists, it will fill with NULL)
3. Or you have to find all possible "bad lines" (beginning with [INFO, Downloading, empty, etc)
4. You can count your seperator per line and take all lines that have the same amount of it
5. Or maybe you can work with a little bit of try except:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""bdasdjosa
fisaonfoasd
dkosap dksaop ksa dsfdsd
col1;col2;col3
1;4.4;99
2;4.5;200
3;4.7;65
4;3.2;140
dsdsadsas adsadsa
sadasds""")

skipped = []
while True:
    try:
        # try to read data
        df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";", skiprows=skipped, header=None)
        break
    except pd.errors.ParserError:
        TESTDATA.seek(0)
        # add next skipping line
        skipped.append(len(skipped))

# reset header, because there is (in my testcases) always one row more than needed
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

# Remove dirty lines (from end of df)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Example output:

```
0 col1 col2 col3
1    1  4.4   99
2    2  4.5  200
3    3  4.7   65
4    4  3.2  140
```

If this all dows not help, you need to provide more data

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I currently have a similar dirty solution put together. I might add some of the things you wrote, just to avoid running into more exceptions that I am not yet aware of.